# Convert Date with TimeStamp into NSString iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to convert my device current time into Zone (`America/New_york`)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"]];
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
```

`start` now has the device current time in `IST`. How can I convert it into zone '*America*'

I planned to do the below

```
start = [dateFormatter dateFromString:<start date String>];
```

A Day is categorised into 3 divisions based on a time period.

```
Say 08:00 - 15:00 AS PHASE1
    15:00 - 17:00 AS PHASE2
    17:00 - 20:00 AS PHASE3
    20:00 - 08:00 AS TRANSITION PHASE and can be ignored.
```

Am just taking device's date and append the time string to identify in which phase it is.

Example:  Indian Time is 05-FEB-2014 01:25 AM (Device Date)

Considering `15:00` as first cutoff.. I append the '`05-FEB-2014`' to `15:00` and digest it as *American* timezone.. Which resolves and gives me `06-FEB-2014 02:30 IST`(Cut off Date).. So the difference between the both days goes greater than one day!

My expected result could be take device time also in American Timezone and compare with the compare with the nearest cut off time.

Comment: Stuck on what?  You don't know how to derive "<start date String>"?

Comment: @HotLicks, yes.. If I am wrong in this approach, any other way to convert the time?

Comment: (An NSDate is (almost) always expressed in UTC internally -- it contains no timezone offset.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSDate` does not have a time zone. It's a single time reference that's valid anywhere. It's basically just an object wrapper for `NSTimeInterval`-- all it stores is the number of seconds since a reference date. Time zones only apply when converting to/from user-visible strings.

You can get a user-visible string from your date formatter as

```
NSString *localizedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:start];
```

But converting `NSDate` to a particular time zone is not a meaningful goal. There's no time zone on `NSDate`, so it's not a conversion that can be applied.

Comment: Using a date formatter will give you a string containing the time in whatever time zone you want. What specifically do you need besides that?

Answer (score 5):

Date of new york :

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"Date : %@", dateString);
```

Date of all zones :

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSArray *timeZoneNames = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];

for (NSString *name in timeZoneNames) {
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:name];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"timeZone abbreviation : %@\nName : \"%@\"\nDate : %@\n\n", [timeZone abbreviation], name, dateString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the `stringFromDate` Method in the dateformatter. You pass in an `NSDate`and it converts to the specified format.

**UPDATE**: Here is how you set the current time zone `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];`

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html